# Is it possible to run ansible on a specific host and specify a group

Tags: ansible

I am currently running a playbook on a specific host using something like the following command:

```
ansible-playbook webserver.yml -i 127.0.0.1,
```

What I would like to do is specify the environment (i.e. dev,stage,prod) in this command line and have a yaml file for each environment. Does anyone know a way to achieve this? We are trying to avoid having a central list of files for all our inventory.

TIA

Comment: I think [Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-setup-examples) resolves your problem.

`ansible-playbook -i inventory_test webserver.yml` 

But there are also several ways to achieve this. This is one of them. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks #BinaryBullet. Yes, I didn't realize you could pass multiple -i options. Looks like I can create a file per env (dev.yml, stage.ymn, prod.yml) and pass that in with the call.

Answer (score 1):

In Amazon Web Services you are able to use tags in the hosts definiton of your playbook:

> - hosts: "tag_Type_apache:&tag_Environment_{{tag_env}}"
>
> roles:
>         - apache_ws_config

You can then pass in the tag_env variable at runtime allowing you to run your plays on specific server types in specific environments. This way you dont need to maintain a list of servers. I'm betting there are ways to do this with other cloud providers or esxi as well.

You can also have a separate hosts/inventory file if you arent using aws that has your hosts by env:

> [usnonprod]
>
> 10.x.x.x var1=host1
>
> 10.x.x.y var1=host2
>
> [usprd]
>
> 10.y.x.x var1=host1
>
> 10.y.x.y var1=host2

You can then use those groups (usprd, usnonprod, etc) in your hosts entry of your playbook like so:

hosts: usnonprod

when calling: ansible-playbook -i inventoryfile.yml letsplay.yml

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html